# How do I filter a list by type in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a function that outputs a list of an image and a feature collection. I'd like to use a filter to separate them. `ee.filter.hasType()` looks like what I want, but I can't figure out how to implement it. More broadly, lots of the filters have this (leftField, rightValue, rightField, leftValue) argument structure that I find confusing.

For example, to filter the image I tried this:

`myFunctionOutput.filter(ee.Filter.hasType({leftField: "type", rightValue: ee.Image()}))`

But this isn't right. What's the proper way to filter a list by type?

Comment: Could you add an example of your working code to test the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That filter argument structure is optimized for the most common use case of filtering a piece of metadata by a constant, in a collection.  E.g.:

```
ee.Filter.lt({leftField: "CLOUD_COVER", rightValue: 10}))
```

which is the same as:

```
ee.Filter.lt("CLOUD_COVER", 10)
```

Sometimes, however, you want to compare a property vs another property, so you have to specify "this is a property name, not a string literal to compare against:

```
ee.Filter.lt({leftField: "CLOUD_COVER", rightField: "cloud_threshold"}),
```

and occasionally, there's a need to have the left value be a literal (e.g.: geometry filtering).

As is (vaguely) implied by the docs for ee.List.filter, there's currently no way to filter on type for Images or Features in a list:

> To filter list items that aren't images or features, test a property
> named 'item', e.g.: ee.Filter.gt('item', 3)

When examining a List element that is an Image or a Feature, any property name you specify in the filter will be taken to be a property inside the list element.  So to make things work by specifically examining type, you'd need to map over the elements in the list setting a type on each one, then filter for that type:

```
var images = ee.List([ee.Image(1), ee.Feature(null, {})])
    .map(function(item) { return ee.Feature(item).set('type', ee.Algorithms.ObjectType(item)) })
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('type', 'Image'))
```

It's safe (in this limited case) to cast the Images to Feature to get at the set() function.  It shouldn't mess anything up.

But a better solution is to just filter for an image-only property (e.g.: `system:bands`) being non-null to get at the images, and use `ee.Filter.notNull(...).not()` to get at the features.

```
ee.List([ee.Image(1), ee.Feature(null, {})])
    .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['system:bands']))
```